# How to get everything in a string up to the 2nd or 3rd comma in postgresql?

Tags: sql, string, postgresql

I already had help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51021788/how-to-cut-off-strings-before-4th-occurrence-of-a-character-in-postgresql).

But when I tried switching from spaces to commas it didn't work

Basically if I have an address:

```
FLAT 10, ELGAR HOUSE, CHURCHILL GARDENS, LONDON, SW1V 3BS
```

I need to cut it and have as output only

```
FLAT 10, ELGAR HOUSE
```

How to do it in postgresql?

Comment: 2nd or 3rd commas?  We really can't make that decision for you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use `split_part` function to get string before occurrence of 2nd comma

```
select split_part(address, ',', 1) || ',' || split_part(address, ',', 2)
from your_table
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/695f4/5)